# Issue with infinite loop in radix tree implementation

Tags: c, string, binary-tree, infinite-loop, radix-tree

I'm having trouble with my radix tree implementation. The idea is that I create the first node, then enter a number of binary numbers. The binary numbers determine whether a left node (0) or a right node (1) is created. Once I reach the end of the binary number, I set a node to "active".

Then I search through the tree to find an active node, and output the original binary numbers again by checking in which direction I had to go to reach the active node.

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int bool;
enum { false, true };

typedef struct radixNode {
    bool active;
    struct radixNode * pnt;
    struct radixNode * l;
    struct radixNode * r;
} node;

void insert(node *root, char * B) {

    printf("String: %s\n", B);
    printf("1st: %c", B[0]);
    printf("\n\n", B);

    // digit is zero so we go left
    if (B[0] == '0') {

        printf("till here if");

        // left child doesn't exist, create it
        if (root->l == NULL) {

            root->l = malloc(sizeof(node));

            /* if the next index in the string does NOT contain a 1 or 0,
            the current index is the last index and the node is activated */
            if (B[1] == 1 || B[1] == 0)
                root->l->active = false;
            else
                root->l->active = true;

            root->l->pnt = root;
            root->l->l = NULL;
            root->l->r = NULL;
            insert(root->l,B++); // B++ removes the first digit of the string
        }

        // left child exists, traverse
        else {
            insert(root->l,B++);
        }
    }

    // digit is one, go right
    else if (B[0] == '1') {
        printf("first was 1\n");

        // right child doesn't exist, create it
        if (root->r == NULL) {

            printf("if triggered\n");

            root->r = malloc(sizeof(node));

            /* if the next index in the string does NOT contain a 1 or 0,
            the current index is the last index and the node is activated */
            if (B[1] == 1 || B[1] == 0)
                root->r->active = false;
            else
                root->r->active = true;

            root->r->pnt = root;
            root->r->l = NULL;
            root->r->r = NULL;
            insert(root->r,B++);
        }

        // left child exists, traverse
        else {
            printf("else triggered\n");
            insert(root->r,B++);
        }
    }
}

node * printTreeMin(node *root) {

    char C[10];

    /* goes left until it can't, appends 0 to string
    till it can't. if node is active, print the string */
    while (root->l != NULL) {

        C[strlen(C)] = '0';

        if (root->active == true)
            printf("%s\n",C);

        root = root->l;
    }

    return root;
}

// prints the next smallest binary number in the tree, returns the node it printed
node * printNextSmallest(node * root) {

    char C[10];

    // if right child exists, go there and find lowest node (after if same deal as printTreeMin() )
    if (root->r != NULL) {

        C[strlen(C)] = '1';
        if (root->active == true)
            printf("%s\n",C);

        root = root->r;

        while (root->l != NULL) {

            C[strlen(C)] = '0';
            if (root->active == true)
                printf("%s\n",C);

            root = root->l;
        }

        return root;
    }

    node * temp = root->pnt;

    while (temp != NULL && root == temp->r) {

        root = temp;
        temp = temp->pnt;
    }

    return temp;
}

void printRadixTree(node *root) {

    root = printTreeMin(root);

    while (printNextSmallest(root) != NULL)
        root = printNextSmallest(root);
}

void test() {

    node * tree = malloc(sizeof(node));
    tree->l = NULL;
    tree->r = NULL;

    // a)
    insert(tree,"101000");
    insert(tree,"10100");
    insert(tree,"10110");
    insert(tree,"101");
    insert(tree,"1111");

    // b)
    printRadixTree(tree);

}

int main() {
    test();
}
```

Here is the output:

```
if triggered
String: 101000
1st: 1

first was 1
if triggered
String: 101000
1st: 1

first was 1
if triggered
String: 101000
1st: 1
```

(and continuing ad infinitum)

Clearly I have an issue within the `insert()` function's recursion but considering I remove the first char of the binary number string when doing the recurrence, I don't understand how it can run infinitely.

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `C[strlen(C)] = '0';`

Comment: BTW: the recursive calls should probabbly be `insert(root->r, B+1);` instead of `insert(root->r, B++);`

Comment: @wildplasser it's supposed to add a 0 to the string which is empty before that. But I just realized as well that that can't be quite right. I think I mixed up some things there.

Comment: That was the issue! B+1 now doesn't have the infinite loop anymore. It still doesn't quite work yet but it's not looping indefinitely anymore. Thanks! Though I got to say I'm confused as to why this would be a problem.

Comment: See the difference between `B++` and `++B` in my answer

Comment: And the funny thing is that the assignments to B[] in the insert() function will segfault, because it is called with a string literal as second argument: `insert(tree,"101000");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the infinite recursion is your choice of auto-increment operator. You want the prefix, not suffix form.

```
insert(..., B++)
```

increments the pointer (stripping the first character) **after** calling insert.

Instead the calls should be

```
insert (..., ++B)
```

You also have problems with your `active` flag, and this is your culprit

```
if (B[1] == 1 || B[1] == 0)
```

I think you meant

```
if (B[1] == '1' || B[1] == '0')
```

The first form is checking for a *binary* zero or one, rather than an ASCII character.

The result of this is that your `active` flag will probably be set incorrectly for most nodes. I expect that will then cause problems when traversing the tree. In fact, `active` will only be set to `false` when you are looking at the last `'0'` or `'1'` in the string (as `B[1]` at that point will be the terminating `'\0'`).

Also, with recusive routines it is always a good idea to make the base case explicit, rather than implicit. Thus, one of the first blocks of code in `insert` should probably be

```
if (B[0] != '1' && B[0] != `0`)
    return;
```

then you can replace the `else if` with a simple `else`

```
if (B[0] == '0')
{
    // ... go left
}
else
{
    // ... go right
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I missed those. I did realize that that would be a problem but apparently didn't change all of them. This hasn't fixed the infinite loop, however. It still appears unchanged (the output as well).

Comment: I added an edit for the infinite loop. There are enough problems in `insert` that they could be combining. You need to clean up the overall structure of the function so that you can be sure of the conditions which trigger a recursion. Such as "Why recurse at all if you set `active` to true?"

Comment: Thanks! I actually had a brainfart there trying to think of a way to do `if (B[0] != '1' && B[0] != '0')` and couldn't figure it out. Will implement that. I have also made a number of other changes and gotten quite a bit farther now to the point where I think I have the `insert()` function working. I still need to get the search to work but that's for another topic.